# how can clear session when i move from a content page to another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site.master with two content page in it.one of content pages have session.I want a code for clear session when i transfer to other content page
how can i do that in asp.net with C# code?

Comment: where is stuffs you tried. show some.?

Answer (score 4):

Clearing the whole Session would be simply:

`Session.Clear();`